# Using Text To Speech on UWP with Xamarin

Tags: c#, xamarin, uwp, text-to-speech, xamarin.uwp

I am working on a Xamarin application and I am trying to use Text To Speech. It works great with Android but I struggle to implement the UWP version.

I've looked at this article on the Microsoft website: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.media.speechsynthesis.speechsynthesizer

The tutorial is very clear until that line:

> MediaElement mediaElement = this.media;

I don't understand how I can access this object in the context of the implementation of a service of a cross platform app, on UWP.

Can anybody give any insight?

Comment: https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/TextToSpeechPlugin

Comment: Thank you very much, I missed this link.

Comment: @BrandonMinnick Could you converter the comment into the answer for this issue?

Comment: @NicoZhu-MSFT Sure, no problem!

Comment: @Toto I added a more-detailed answer, below! If it answers your question, let's mark it as the "Accepted Answer" to help devs with similar questions in the future!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Answer

Add the [Text to Speech Plugin](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Xam.Plugins.TextToSpeech/) to your UWP project and any Netstandard/PCL project(s).

To trigger the Text-To-Speech plugin, use `CrossTextToSpeech.Current.Speak`.

## Example

```
string textToSpeak = "Hello World";
await CrossTextToSpeech.Current.Speak(textToSpeak);
```